# How to compute the image of A only knowing A's eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

$\lambda_1 = -1$

$\lambda_2 = 2$

$
v_1 = <1,1>$

$
v_2 = <1,2>$

Knowing only the above, and without calculating A, how do I find out $Aw$ where $w$ = <1,-1>?

Comment: Do you want the image of $A$ or $A^*$? Please, write the title accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the note. I edited the last part of it. I hope it's a little more clear, now.

Comment: So, now you know how to follow my hint.

Answer (score 1):

*(based on the title, I'm supposing that you want to compute the image of $A$)*

**Hint:** Since $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is a basis you can write $w=(1,-1)$ as linear combination of $v_1,v_2$ and use the fact that $A$ is linear and the fact that you know what is the images of $v_1,v_2$.

Comment: @Cormano, please, see my comment below your question. Don't type * to represent product. $A^*$ is completely different of $A$.

Comment: Please tell me if I followed up on your hint your correctly: I found the coordinate vector of _w_ with respect to the basis. Then, I found the image of A under $v_1$ and $v_2$, respectively, and multiplied them by the corresponding components of the coordinate vector. Finally, I added the products. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. $A(w)=A(\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2)=\alpha_1 A(v_1)+\alpha_2A(v_2)=\alpha_1\lambda_1v_1+\alpha_2\lambda_2v_2$.